# Parsing an array of integers into a single int with Java

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, int

I am trying to make this work as a Python user forced to use Java:

```
private int parseInt(char[]){
        private int parsed = 0
        for (i=0 ; i < char.length(); i++;)
         {parsed += (10**i) * char[i];}
            }
```

I need to know why this method refuses to work and also how to fix it without using a built in function

Comment: "Refuses to work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: I see at least two syntax errors in your code (a missing semicolon in the second line and an extra one in the third line). You may want to start with fixing them.

Comment: You need to describe what you are trying to do. Then you need to describe why this method you posted doesn't do it. If there is an error you need to post it in its entirety. You should also post a few sets is inputs and outputs for clarity.

Comment: I suggest you write something which would work in python and attempt to translate it.  You appear to assume the number is backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change `10**i` to `Math.pow(10,i)`.

Then name your `char[]` array. Let's call it `c`.

Then, change `c[i]`  to `c[i]-'0'`, assuming `c[i]` is a digit.

```
private int parseInt(char[] c)
{
    int parsed = 0;
    for (i=0 ; i < c.length; i++)
        parsed += Math.pow(10,i) * (c[i]-'0');
    return parsed;
}
```

Comment: I prefer [`Character.numericValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) for conversion as it's more self-documenting that offsetting against `'0'`.

Comment: btw, this assumes the number is written in reverse order.

Comment: Math.pow is pretty slow and produces a double.